# How to I sniff this from iTunes?

Tags: ip, traffic, packet-sniffer

If you have used Firebug, you know that you can see the "AJAX" requests back and forth.
And you can see the headers sent.

I would like the same thing. Except, I would like to sniff iTunes. I want to know the REST API that iTunes uses to talk to the cloud. As well as the user-agent and headers sent.

Comment: How do you mean 'talk to the cloud'? what cloud do you think it talks to?

Comment: @Chopper3, I would guess the idea is to try and reverse engineer the iTunes Communication with the iTunes store.  Or perhaps he is trying to hack into the DRM authentication.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the iTunes communication you would like to monitor is REST based and not some proprietary protocol?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: I am capture all the data. But, how do I see exactly what parameters and what URL is iTunes going to?  I want it to be like FireBug, where I can copy the AJAX url.

Comment: I believe iTunes uses SSL for communication with its store.  Short of doing some pretty advanced hacking it may not be possible to accomplish anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use something like [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/). It will allow you to sniff all the packets coming in and out of your machine.

Comment: Ethereal is now [and has been for some time] Wireshark. If you check the linked site, which you provided, has not been updated in several years.

Comment: As the original author of both Ethereal and Wireshark I can confirm that jscott is correct. Ethereal is long dead. Please stop using it.

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks it's cool to see the author of Ethereal and Wireshark on the forum commenting on a question pertaining to his software?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). A bit easier to read than the raw packet capture from Wireshark. Additionally, it allows you to mess with requests/responses sent.

Also check out [this](http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/article.php/3631066/Fiddler-Can-Make-Debugging-Easy.htm) developer article on how to use it effectively.

NOTE: It captures HTTP(s) traffic on the wire so it can be used with virtually any program.